# Extract Layers form .slpk File

Tags: arcgis-pro, 3d, 3d-analyst, 3d-model, scene-layer-package

I have been given an .slpk file generated by Drone2Map. I can import the .slpk file into ArcGIS Pro but I'm unable to edit the 3D layers in the package.
[image]

I have not been able to find a way to extract the layer data from the .slpk file so that I can make it editable. Is there a way to do this?